# Sorting Objects Alphanumerically

Tags: android, rx-java, kotlin

I am running into an issue when trying to sort a List of "Routes" for my app, no matter what I try, I cannot obtain the sorting that I am looking for.

I want it sorted 1,2,3,4,5, etc but when I sort, I get 1,11,12,2,20 and so on.

My Route model is

```
public open class Route(docValue:Map<String,Any>) {
    val route_id = (docValue["route_id"] as Number).toInt()
    val short_name = docValue["route_short_name"] as String
    val color = readColorMoreSafely(docValue, "route_color", Color.BLUE)
    val long_name = docValue["route_long_name"] as String 
}
```

The code used to sort is

```
if(cityId != null && view != null) {
        val routesList = view.findViewById(R.id.routesList) as ListView
        val cache = TransitCache.getInstance(applicationContext, cityId, true)
        val routes = cache.getRoutes()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnNext {
                val noRoutesMessage = view.findViewById(R.id.list_routes_no_routes_visible) as TextView
                noRoutesMessage.visibility = if(it.size == 0) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
            }
        routes.toSortedList()
        listAdapter = RxListAdapter(applicationContext, R.layout.activity_list_routes_row, routes)
        routesList.adapter = listAdapter
```

But still nothing, I just want to sort the routes by "route_id", i've tried a few different things, the last one of which was

```
routes.toSortedList()
```

which still ended up not doing what I wanted, at this point I'm stuck.

Comment: Note that functions like `routes.toSortedList()` on readonly lists in Kotlin stdlib copy the list and return a new list, so your variable `routes` was not actaully changed into a sorted list but rather you made a copy and threw it away because you didn't assign it.  `val sortedRoutes = routes.toSortedList()` and then use `sortedRoutes` later instead of the original list.

Comment: @JaysonMinard there is no such extension function (`toSortedList`) in kotlin stdlib. It is the member function of `rx.Observable`

Comment: I was generically talking about that type of function.  `toSortedList` also returns a new `Observable` that must be used instead of the original yes?  same problem, it does not in-place sort the original, you have to use the resulting reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val routes = cache.getRoutes()
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

This code tells me you're dealing with RxJava, which requires an entirely different solution so in the future it is important to include that type of information.

If `cache.getRoutes()` returns an `Observable<List<Route>>` then that route can be sorted with the code

```
.map { 
    it.sortedBy(Route::route_id)
}
```

This will produce a new inner list sorted by the numerical value of `route_id`.

If `cache.getRoutes()` returns `Observable<Route>` then you need to include the additional call to `.toList()` to turn it into an `Observable<List<Route>>`.

Comment: The question author wants to sort routes based on routeId number and not its string representation.

Comment: It would be more idiomatically to use `sortedBy` inside the `map` operation, like in the answer of @mfulton26

Comment: @Ilya Ah, I actually misread and thought the aim was a lexical sorting, thats my bad

Comment: @Kiskae if you ever need anything, like a kidney or part of my liver...it is yours. You have saved me so much time.

Answer (score 2):

If `routes` is a [`MutableList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/) and you want to sort it in-place then you can use [`sortBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort-by.html):

```
routes.sortBy(Route::route_id)
```

Otherwise you can use [`sortedBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by.html) to create a new list with the elements sorted:

```
val sortedRoutes = routes.sortedBy(Route::route_id)
```

Comment: Trying both of these gives me Receiver type mismatch errors. 
val sortedRoute = routes.sortedBy(Route::route_id)

Comment: What is the type of `routes`? `List<Route>`?

Comment: @mfulton26 I suggest to assign the result of the `sortedBy` to some variable, otherwise it looks like `sortedBy` does side-effect on the `routes`

Comment: Good point @Ilya. I've updated the example to assigned the result to a new variable, `sortedRoutes`. Thank you.